# Java - confusing behavior during static initialization

Tags: java, variables, printing, static, initialization

I was testing java's "statics" a bit and found some things I don't get. Look at these codes:

```
public class X {
    public static int staticInit = 0;
    public static int staticInitRe = 0;
    public static int classicInitRe = 0;
}

public class Y extends X {
    public static int staticInitRe;
    public static int classicInitRe = 1;
    static {
        staticInitRe = 1;
        staticInit = 1;
    }
}
```

(where "Re" stands for "redeclared")

I made two Main classes for printing and loading

## 1.

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("staticInit X: "+X.staticInit);
        System.out.println("staticInitRe X: "+X.staticInitRe);
        System.out.println("classicInitRe X: "+X.classicInitRe);
        System.out.println("");

        System.out.println("staticInit Y: "+Y.staticInit);
        System.out.println("staticInitRe Y: "+Y.staticInitRe);
        System.out.println("classicInitRe Y: "+Y.classicInitRe);
        System.out.println("");

        System.out.println("staticInit X: "+X.staticInit);
        System.out.println("staticInitRe X: "+X.staticInitRe);
        System.out.println("classicInitRe X: "+X.classicInitRe);
        System.out.println("");

        System.out.println("staticInit Y: "+Y.staticInit);
        System.out.println("staticInitRe Y: "+Y.staticInitRe);
        System.out.println("classicInitRe Y: "+Y.classicInitRe);
        System.out.println("");

    }
}
```

output:

```
staticInit X: 0
staticInitRe X: 0
classicInitRe X: 0

staticInit Y: 0
staticInitRe Y: 1
classicInitRe Y: 1

staticInit X: 1
staticInitRe X: 0
classicInitRe X: 0

staticInit Y: 1
staticInitRe Y: 1
classicInitRe Y: 1
```

## 2.

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("staticInit X: "+X.staticInit);
        System.out.println("");

        System.out.println("staticInit Y: "+Y.staticInit);
        System.out.println("");

        System.out.println("staticInit X: "+X.staticInit);
        System.out.println("");

        System.out.println("staticInit Y: "+Y.staticInit);
        System.out.println("");

    }
}
```

output:

```
staticInit X: 0

staticInit Y: 0

staticInit X: 0

staticInit Y: 0
```

I don't understand what happens with the `staticInit` variable. In the output of the first snippet, I think it should be respectively `0, 1, 0, 1` or `0, 1, 1, 1`, not `0, 0, 1, 1`.

I also don't get why in the second snippet it changes to `0, 0, 0, 0` after removing prints of the other variables.

Answer (score 3):

`staticInit` is a static variable of class `X`. Therefore, when you access it, only class `X` is initialized. This is true even when you access it via `Y.staticInit`. `Y.staticInit` and `X.staticInit` are the same variable.

Only when you access the first static variables of `Y` (`Y.staticInitRe` in your first snippet), class `Y` is initialized, which also changes the value of `X.staticInit` to 1.

On the other hand, `X.staticInitRe` and `Y.staticInitRe` are different variables and `X.classicInitRe` and `Y.classicInitRe` are different variables.

The first snippet :

```
    System.out.println("staticInit X: "+X.staticInit); // X is initialized. All all of its 
                                                       // variables are initialized to 0
    System.out.println("staticInitRe X: "+X.staticInitRe);
    System.out.println("classicInitRe X: "+X.classicInitRe);
    System.out.println("");

    System.out.println("staticInit Y: "+Y.staticInit); // Y is not initialized yet
    System.out.println("staticInitRe Y: "+Y.staticInitRe); // Y is initialized: 
                                                           // Y.staticInitRe, 
                                                           // Y.classicInitRe and 
                                                           // X.staticInit are assigned 1
                                                           // before this String is output
    System.out.println("classicInitRe Y: "+Y.classicInitRe);
    System.out.println("");

    System.out.println("staticInit X: "+X.staticInit); // was changed to 1 by Y's
                                                       // static initializer
    System.out.println("staticInitRe X: "+X.staticInitRe); // remains 0
    System.out.println("classicInitRe X: "+X.classicInitRe); // remains 0
    System.out.println("");

    System.out.println("staticInit Y: "+Y.staticInit);
    System.out.println("staticInitRe Y: "+Y.staticInitRe);
    System.out.println("classicInitRe Y: "+Y.classicInitRe);
    System.out.println("");
```

The second snippet doesn't access any variables or methods of class `Y`, so class `Y` is not initialized, and `X.staticInit` remains 0.

[JLS 12.4.1.](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-12.html#jls-12.4.1) specifies when a class is initialized:

> 12.4.1. When Initialization Occurs
>
> A class or interface type T will be initialized immediately before the
>   first occurrence of any one of the following:
>
> - T is a class and an instance of T is created.
> - A static method declared by T is invoked.
> - A static field declared by T is assigned.
> - **A static field declared by T is used and the field is not a constant variable (§4.12.4).**
> - T is a top level class (§7.6) and an assert statement (§14.10) lexically nested within T (§8.1.3) is executed.

Since `Y.staticInit` is **not** declared in `Y`, using that field doesn't initialize class `Y`.